# Linq order by Seq Number but also have records with deleted flag ordered last

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a table with a sequence number, and a deleted date. The date is null normally but if it's set that means it's been deleted.

How can I order by sequence number but also have the deleted records ordered last?

Right now I'm trying to do something like-

```
var records= db.Records.Where(x => x.Record.otherId == otherId)
                       .OrderBy(x => x.SEQ_NUMBER).ThenBy(x => x.DELETED_DATE);
```

Comment: first sort by Deleted_Date, then by SEQ_Number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First order by `Deleted_Date` and then by the `Seq_Number`:

```
db.Records.Where(x => x.Record.otherId == otherId)
          .OrderBy(x => x.DELETED_DATE)
          .ThenBy(x => x.SEQ_NUMBER);
```

This way the ones with `NULL` (not deleted) will appear first and then the deleted ones

Comment: @JoeViscardi - Cool :) glad to help

Comment: @JoeViscardi - Please consider marking question as solved :)

Comment: got it, was making me wait 7 minutes